# unix command to delete line break for php command

Tags: php, unix, command-line

I have php files with SQL queries broken into multiples lines.
for example:

```
$sql = "select count( aa." . BOOK_ART_ID . ") as book_count
                from " . BOOK_ART_TABLE . " as aa
                inner join " . AUTHER_TABLE . " as l on aa." . BOOK_ART_AUTHER_ID . " = l." . AUTHER_ID . " AND
                    l." . AUTHER_CODE . " = '" . "'     
                where aa." . BOOK_ART_TITLE_ID . " = " . $book_id;
```

I'm trying to extract all SQL statements from the PHP files. I tried grep on $sql and only getting the first line back.

How do I extract entire SQL string from all PHP files?

I was thinking more around deleted line break until ';' character.

Comment: Seeing as the SQL contains PHP constants, what use it this going to be? You'd be better off to parse the string in PHP and output it no?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed -n '/\$sql/{ :loop; N; s/ *\n *//g; /;/{p;q}; t loop}' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ sed -n '/\$sql/{ :loop; N; s/ *\n *//g; /;/{p;q}; t loop}' yourfile
$sql = "select count( aa." . BOOK_ART_ID . ") as book_countfrom " . BOOK_ART_TABLE . " as aainner join " . AUTHER_TABLE . " as l on aa." . BOOK_ART_AUTHER_ID . " = l." . AUTHER_ID . " ANDl." . AUTHER_CODE . " = '" . "'where aa." . BOOK_ART_TITLE_ID . " = " . $book_id;
```